# Redirect if the user didn't bought an item

Tags: php, woocommerce, product, shortcode

This is the best I've gotten so far, but I'm getting many errors.

Starting with the main issue; it does redirect to the correct url but the page is showing nothing.

Here is what I am attempting: [Reference code](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/101498/redirect-function-inside-a-shortcode/101515)

Here is my code.

```
function pre_process_shortcode() {
  if (!is_singular()) return;
  global $post;
  $user = wp_get_current_user();
  $product_id = 27;
  $product_bought = wc_customer_bought_product( $user->user_email, $user->ID , $product_id );
  if (!empty($post->post_content)) {
    $regex = get_shortcode_regex();
    preg_match_all('/'.$regex.'/',$post->post_content,$matches);
    if (!empty($matches[2]) && in_array('protactPage',$matches[2]) && $product_bought && is_user_logged_in()) {
      wp_redirect('https://learndigital-mena.com/cart-2/');
        exit();
    } else {
      // login form or redirect to login page
         wp_redirect('https://learndigital-mena/my-account/');
        exit();
    }
  }
}
add_action('template_redirect','pre_process_shortcode',1);
```

Comment: Omar, it seems you did not properly add the link and only the reference text made it into your question, please edit your question and reapply the reference code  link properly, make sure the link itself is added.

Comment: Okay, i will add it to your question for you.

Comment: Here : https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/101498/redirect-function-inside-a-shortcode/101515

Comment: Please edit your question and apply any textual edits to your link content ;) Simply hit the edit button on the bottom of your question and add to or edit the text/link I added.

Answer (score 0):

Note this is only client side and not server side :
You can try to replace `wp_redirect('https://learndigital-mena/my-account/');` to `echo '<script>window.location="https://learndigital-mena/my-account/"</script>';` or `header("Location: https://learndigital-mena/my-account/")`, but header location will be at the top of the script.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, unfortunately didn't work. also if it did work I think if I user was disabling JavaScript it might cause a problem.

Comment: Check this post: (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/768431/how-do-i-make-a-redirect-in-php)